# How to reference a value diagonally in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Here's a sample table:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | *3* | B1 | C1 | D1 | E1 |
| **2** | A2 | *6* | C2 | D2 | E2 |
| **3** | A3 | B3 | *0* | D3 | E3 |
| **4** | A4 | B4 | C4 | *2* | E4 |
| **5** | A5 | B5 | C5 | D5 | *8* |

Let's say in a column I want to reference values in A1 to E5 diagonally (*in italics*), how do I do so.

It looks like this in the column:

| diagonal values |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 6 |
| 0 |
| 2 |
| 8 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapt the formula below. It uses the `INDEX` and `ROWS` functions to get the diagonal values based on their column position. Then `IFERROR` function is used to insert empty values when there is an error (no value found).

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A1:$E1,,ROWS($1:1)),"")
```

Drag the formula down to fill the other cells.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### Copy Down Offset Formula

Two input values:

1. The absolute reference to the first diagonal cell (e.g. `$A$1`)
2. The first row # of your output (e.g. `3`) is entered twice

```
=OFFSET($A$1, ROW()-3, ROW()-3)
```

[image]

#### Range-Based Formula

One input value: data range

```
=LET(rng, A1:E5,
     MAP(SEQUENCE(MIN(ROWS(rng), COLUMNS(rng))),
         LAMBDA(s, INDEX(rng, s, s))))
```

[image: Range-Based Formula]

1. [LET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) function assigns the name **`rng`** to the input range to make it easier to reuse in the formula.
2. [MAP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/map-function-48006093-f97c-47c1-bfcc-749263bb1f01) passes a [SEQUENCE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90) of numbers into a [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function. The [SEQUENCE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90) starts at 1, increments by 1, and the ending number is determined by applying the MIN function against the number of rows and columns in **`rng`**.   This `MIN(height, width)` approach avoids `#REF!` errors if `height <> width`
3. The [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function uses an arbitrarily named variable **`s`** to represent each mapped value from the [SEQUENCE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90) in its formula.
4. For each mapped **`s`**, [INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) returns the value in **`rng`** at index **`s,s`** (row,column)